# Regex to remove and then rename file

Tags: terminal

I'm using terminal on OSX along with the find command to find *.txt files and then rm them with the current time/date stamp. All my files which find locates consists of filename_day_month_year_hour. What I would like to do is to do is replace the filename part and add the current time/date stamp?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Bash, but it would be something like this:

```
for $i in `find /where *.txt` mv $i `date`.txt;
```

Comment: This will not work. First of all, if `find` outputs any file with a space in its name, this won't be passed to `$i` properly. Also, since `$(date)` expands to `Wed Jan 9 10:34:13 CET 2013`, for example, the `mv` wouldn't see the correct argument either—it needs to be quoted. Finally, this isn't even the correct syntax for Bash. After `for`, there should be a `; do mv …; done`.

Comment: Cool beans. I said it was a bit since I used bash anyway but I knew it was a one liner. Kudoz